# Redirect visitors to a "site in maintenance" page?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, redirect

My site is in maintenance(construction). How to redirect visitors to a "site in maintenance" single page?

I heard something about app_offline.htm for ASP.NET.

Is there something similar for PHP?

- I want that every page from "mysite.com" be redirected to "mysite.com/maintenance.php";
- I don't want to do the minimum modification in the existing site pages, ideally no one.

> Apache version *2.2.15*
>   PHP version *5.2.13*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Apache with mod_rewrite create a `.htaccess` file in the `DocumentRoot` folder containing:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/maintenance.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$

# here filter the developer's IP/
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^888\.888\.888\.888

RewriteRule $ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

In apache with `mod_rewrite` you can do it easily, just make the first rule something like

```
RewriteRule /.* /maintenance.html [L]
```

If you want to be able to test the site while everybody else sees the maintenance page, you can also add a condition, excluding some IP addresses, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ! example.com
RewriteRule /.* /maintenance.html [L]
```